# What does a function signature without implementation mean in a class definition?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, signature

Unfortunately, I can't show code, but here's the story:
I'm supposed to learn how a program we use at work works. I traced the flow of data from a user interface element into the deep internals of a function. But now, inside of a class definition I got stuck. The data I'm tracking is passed to a function. In the class there's a line with a function signature for that function, but no implementation.

How do I go about finding the implementation? All the code (except for Microsoft's) was developed in house and should reside within the project, but Go To Definition only brings me back to the signature.

We're using C# and .Net 4.0.

Here's the line:

```
public abstract class SomethingDoer : SomethingElse
    // ...
    protected abstract void DoSomething(T1 param1, T2 param2, T3 param3);
```

Now I'm looking for the implementing class by looking for References to SomethingDoer, but unfortunately the break point isn't hitting. Do I have the wrong class or am I missing something about abstract functions?

Comment: Show the line you found, is it abstract, partial?

Comment: You could be looking at the meta-data for a class referenced in a DLL you don't have the source for. Without code we will never really know. Does the code file tab say something like "File name [from metadata]"?

Comment: @AlexK. it is abstract. I totally overlooked this. Thanks for this hint. Now I'll go on the hunt for classes implementing this class.

Comment: @lowerkey You might not be able to post the exact code showing what you mean (as it presumably is proprietary to your company), but you can easily show eqivalent code. Showing us `protected abstract void DoSomething();` would have been enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without code this is really hard to answer.  A function definition without implementation is usually an interface or abstract.  Interfaces can have **only** definitions, while abstract can mix both:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {
    void SomeMethod();
}

public abstract SomeAbstractClass {
    public abstract void SomeMethod();

    public void AwesomeMethod() {
        // I do awesome things; look at my method body!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking at the source code, it could be

1. an `abstract` method
2. a `partial` method
3. an `extern` method

In the first case, the implementation is in the class deriving from this class. In the second case, the implementation is in another "part" of the definition of this class, probably in another file. In the third case the implementation is inside some (native) DLL that is being imported.

Another possibility is that you're not actually looking at the source code, but only at metadata generated from an assembly reference in your C# project file.

So which of the keywords `abstract`, `partial`, or `extern` do you see with the method?

Answer (score 0):

It's mean you have only compiled class without sorces. May be some DLLs?

Comment: What's weird about this is that some functions are implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly looking at an interface?

Interfaces have the defined functions but no implementation. It's used to show that they exist and must conform to a spec.

Can't you post sample code and change the wording for us to see?